# Makefile C++ inheritance

Tags: c++, inheritance, makefile

The following are the files involved and a short description:

`arrayListType.h`, `arrayListTypeImp.cpp`: declare and implement `arrayListType` class and its functions.

`unorderedarrayListType.h` `unorderedArrayListTypeImp.cpp`: inherit `arrayListType` class and declare `unorderedarrayListType` class and implement virtual functions of `arrayListType` class.

`Ch13_Ex6.cpp`: Instantiates an object of class `unorderedArrayListType` and runs some tests.

I am having a compilation error, which I think is due to the Makefile. The following is the error:

```
unorderedArrayListTypeImp.cpp:4: error: expected unqualified-id before 'using'
unorderedArrayListTypeImp.cpp: In member function 'virtual void unorderedArrayListType::insertAt(int, int)':
unorderedArrayListTypeImp.cpp:11: error: 'cout' was not declared in this scope
unorderedArrayListTypeImp.cpp:11: error: 'endl' was not declared in this scope
unorderedArrayListTypeImp.cpp:13: error: 'cout' was not declared in this scope
```

Line 4 has a `using namespace std;` command. The line before that is `#include "arrayListType.h"`. I have tried the following variations in the Makefile but neither worked:

Version 1

```
all: Ch13_Ex6

arrayListTypeImp.o: arrayListType.h arrayListTypeImp.cpp
    g++ -c -Wall arrayListType.h arrayListTypeImp.cpp

unorderedArrayListTypeImp.o: arrayListTypeImp.o unorderedArrayListType.h unorderedArrayListTypeImp.cpp
    g++ -c -Wall arrayListTypeImp.o unorderedArrayListType.h unorderedArrayListTypeImp.cpp

Ch13_Ex6.o: Ch13_Ex6.cpp
    g++ -c -Wall Ch13_Ex6.cpp

Ch13_Ex6: arrayListTypeImp.o unorderedArrayListTypeImp.o Ch13_Ex6.o
    g++ -Wall Ch13_Ex6.o arrayListTypeImp.o unorderedArrayListTypeImp.o -o Ch13_Ex6
```

Version 2:

```
all: Ch13_Ex6

arrayListTypeImp.o: arrayListType.h arrayListTypeImp.cpp
    g++ -c -Wall arrayListType.h arrayListTypeImp.cpp

unorderedArrayListTypeImp.o: unorderedArrayListType.h unorderedArrayListTypeImp.cpp
    g++ -c -Wall unorderedArrayListType.h unorderedArrayListTypeImp.cpp

Ch13_Ex6.o: Ch13_Ex6.cpp
    g++ -c -Wall Ch13_Ex6.cpp

Ch13_Ex6: arrayListTypeImp.o unorderedArrayListTypeImp.o Ch13_Ex6.o
    g++ -Wall Ch13_Ex6.o arrayListTypeImp.o unorderedArrayListTypeImp.o -o Ch13_Ex6
```

Both versions compile `arrayListTypeImp.o` and give the error shown above when compiling `unorderedArrayListTypeImp.o`. The following is the complete compile output:

```
make
g++ -c -Wall unorderedArrayListType.h unorderedArrayListTypeImp.cpp 
arrayListTypeImp.o
unorderedArrayListType.h:16: error: expected unqualified-id at end of input
unorderedArrayListTypeImp.cpp:4: error: expected unqualified-id before 'using'
unorderedArrayListTypeImp.cpp: In member function 'virtual void        unorderedArrayListType::insertAt(int, int)':
unorderedArrayListTypeImp.cpp:11: error: 'cout' was not declared in this scope
unorderedArrayListTypeImp.cpp:11: error: 'endl' was not declared in this scope
unorderedArrayListTypeImp.cpp:13: error: 'cout' was not declared in this scope
unorderedArrayListTypeImp.cpp:13: error: 'endl' was not declared in this scope
```

Code for arrayListType.h:

```
#ifndef H_arrayListType
#define H_arrayListType

class arrayListType
{
public:
    bool isEmpty() const;
    bool isFull() const;        
    int listSize() const;        
    int maxListSize() const;        
    void print() const;        
    bool isItemAtEqual(int location, int item) const;

    virtual void insertAt(int location, int insertItem) = 0;        
    virtual void insertEnd(int insertItem) = 0;

    void removeAt(int location);        
    int retrieveAt(int location) const;        
    virtual void replaceAt(int location, int repItem) = 0;

    void clearList();

    virtual int seqSearch(int searchItem) const = 0;

    virtual void remove(int removeItem) = 0;

    arrayListType(int size = 100);        
    arrayListType(const arrayListType& otherList);        
    virtual ~arrayListType();

protected:
    int *list;
    int length;
    int maxSize;
};

#endif
```

Code for unorderArrayListTypeImp.cpp:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "unorderedArrayListType.h"

using namespace std;

void unorderedArrayListType::insertAt(int location, 
                                  int insertItem)
{
    if (location < 0 || location >= maxSize)
        cout << "The position of the item to be inserted "
             << "is out of range." << endl;
    else if (length >= maxSize)  //list is full
        cout << "Cannot insert in a full list" << endl;
    else
    {
        for (int i = length; i > location; i--)
            list[i] = list[i - 1];  //move the elements down

        list[location] = insertItem; //insert the item at 
                                     //the specified position

        length++;   //increment the length
    }
} //end insertAt

void unorderedArrayListType::insertEnd(int insertItem)
{
    if (length >= maxSize)  //the list is full
        cout << "Cannot insert in a full list." << endl;
    else
    {
        list[length] = insertItem; //insert the item at the end
        length++; //increment the length
    }
} //end insertEnd

// More virtual functions implemented and finally a constructor

unorderedArrayListType::unorderedArrayListType(int size)
                       : arrayListType(size)
{
}  //end constructor
```

Comment: If you are getting a **compiler** error, what makes you think that you can fix it in the Makefile?

Comment: I got a similar error when I changed the order for Ch13_Ex6, where I gave Ch13_Ex6.o before arrayListTypeImp.o and unorderedArrayListTypeImp.o. So it tried compiling Ch13_Ex.0 from its .cpp file and it gave the exact same error. I changed that order and that error was gone and arrayListTypeImp.o compiled since it was first in the list. But now I am having a problem with unorderedArrayListTypeImp.o

Comment: this error has nothing to do with Makefile's or the order in which things are built.

Comment: OK, please post the code for `unorderedArrayListType.h` and `unorderedArrayListTypeImp.cpp` too since I don't see any error in the header you posted. And **please** format it as code so it's readable!

Comment: Follow Evan's suggestion and post the `unorderedArrayListTypeImp.h` header too. Seems like you're doing something wrong in there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You did not `#include <iostream>` in arrayListType.h, but did it in arrayListType.cpp, before you `#include "arrayListType.h"` there. You need to place `#include <iostream>` into arrayListType.h before you use std::cout or std::endl.

To avoid such mistakes it is good to place the interface header as the first #include statement int the implementation file.

Comment: thanks @Evan, @Rudi, @Victor. I corrected as directed by Rudi and Evan and the code is working now.

Answer (score 3):

I am guessing that the error is in `unorderedArrayListType.h`, you likely have a missing semicolon or something. Looking in the Makefile will do nothing to solve that error.

**EDIT:** Woah, there actually is something wrong with your Makefile! Heh, I just looked at it and you have the following:

```
g++ -c -Wall arrayListType.h arrayListTypeImp.cpp
```

Don't pass .h files to g++!, only the .cpp files. So write it like this:

```
g++ -c -Wall arrayListTypeImp.cpp
```

Likewise:

```
g++ -c -Wall unorderedArrayListType.h unorderedArrayListTypeImp.cpp
```

should be:

```
g++ -c -Wall unorderedArrayListTypeImp.cpp
```

Comment: I verified arrayListType.h more than once. Also, arrayListTypeImp.o compiled without any errors. The error is when going to the next line to compile unorderedArrayListTypeImp.o

Comment: @user640639: The error is almost certainly in `arrayListType.h`, post the code for it.

Comment: @user post the code for unorderedArrayListTypeImp.cpp. That's where the error is coming from.

Comment: i am trying to edit. but when i click the edit button, a pop-up like window is appearing saying formatting and not allowing me to format. is that because some one else is formatting it? sorry i am still learning the formatting posts.

Comment: @user you can format it as code by indenting 4 spaces or I suppose you can just copy-paste it and someone else can format it for you.

Answer (score 2):

Evan Teran is probably right. `expected unqualified-id before '...'` usually means you missed a semicolon before that line. If it turns out it really is your makefile, here's some general makefile advice:

1. Use variables. Instead of

   ```
   g++ -c -Wall ...
   ```

   you can do

   ```
   CXX_OPTS= -Wall -O3
   ...
   g++ -c $(CXX_OPTS) ...
   ```
2. Use pattern rules. Rather than

   ```
   arrayListTypeImp.o: arrayListType.h arrayListTypeImp.cpp
       g++ -c -Wall arrayListType.h arrayListTypeImp.cpp

   unorderedArrayListTypeImp.o: unorderedArrayListType.h unorderedArrayListTypeImp.cpp
       g++ -c -Wall unorderedArrayListType.h unorderedArrayListTypeImp.cpp

   Ch13_Ex6.o: Ch13_Ex6.cpp
       g++ -c -Wall Ch13_Ex6.cpp
   ```

   you can use

   ```
   %.o:%.cpp
       g++ $(CXX_OPTS) -c $< -o $@
   ```

This should shorten your makefile and make it easier to debug and find your problem.  If you want more information, check [this](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/) out.

Comment: thanks for the suggestion and links. will try to follow that.